# NodeJS + MySQL hosting (other than Heroku)

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am not able to verify my card for Heroku(wanted to use clearDB), is there any other free hosting service for MySQL and nodeJS beginners can use?

Comment: aws has 1 year free tier

Comment: https://infinityfree.net/ what i can find by google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind putting down a CC ( I think you can use DO without one too) then linode and DigitalOcean both offer 100 credit for 90 days. This allows you to use any of their services. They both offer 5.00 options for node with pre-defined configs and dbass options as well.

As noted, AWS does have free tiers as well for small instances however if your project is to eventually go public, you may wish to plan ahead for that.

Both Linode and Digital ocean offer 5.00 tier so its fairly inexpensive ( AWS offers light sail at the same price as well)

If, the idea is to not ever go public and just learning then running locally may be the way to go, until you are ready to push somthing out.

Comment: What of netlify? Does netlify host node js applications ??